# Process builder and mass update

Tags: process-builder, visual-workflow, governorlimits

My question is about behaver of Process builder when we do mass update with ListView or Data loader. Is it triggered sepeparately for each record? If not and it is mass triggered how can we secure it to not meet limits.

Example:
I have process for object A and it triggers flow. In the flow it looks all of the records B that relate to object A. So if i will mass update 10000 A objects triggering this process. I will end up with 10k SOQLs and error.

Comment: It seems after [Winter '16](http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter16/release-notes/rn_forcecom_process_bulkification.htm), there have been enhancements and that Process Builders are bulkified to handle such scenarios.

Comment: Yep I know and I even tested it but is there any more detailed description how?